# Ordering the loading of scripts in the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files `A.js` and `B.js`. I am importing them in my html as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="B.js"></script>
```

If I define a variable inside `A.js`.

- Can I access variable from A in B?
- What is the order of loading? Can B come before?

Comment: A Google search and cursory testing would answer both points for you. You can answer 1 by, well, creating the variable and attempting to call it, and you can answer 2 by looking in browser's network console.

Comment: @Utkanos, of course I tested, but can I trust that file A is always loaded before?

Comment: well you can define global scope vars outside js files (before loading them) and then interact with them inside files. - It worked for me this way for a client based html game.

Answer (score 3):

From the [HTML spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-script-element.html#attr-script-async):

> There are three possible modes that can be selected using these
>   attributes. If the **async** attribute is present, then the script will be
>   executed asynchronously, as soon as it is available. If the **async**
>   attribute is not present but the **defer** attribute is present, then the
>   script is executed when the page has finished parsing. If neither
>   attribute is present, then the script is fetched and executed
>   immediately, before the user agent continues parsing the page.

So, as long as you are not using `defer` or `async` attributes, `A` will be available to `B.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access that variable from B. But in A you won't be able to access variable of B unless it finishes its loading. Loading will maintain sequence A then B. I will prefer if you use jquery and use document.reday function and access variable inside it. This will wait until your all scripts are loaded then it will start execution. A variable out of any function is a global variable in js so you can access it from anywhere you want.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not considered like other programming languages. First of all, they are loaded consecutively and besides, variables in B are not accessible until B locad is completed.

Another words, under the circumstances you are facing, you cannot call anything in B from A until page load is finished or you may use jQuery document ready.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var test = "";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="A.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="B.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why should he use this?